# If I have a character wearing a hijab, what are some things I need to consider?

Tags: characters

I live in a country where the majority is Muslim. I am not a Muslim, but I have Muslim friends and I didn't think much of adding a hijab character. I have begun to consider the idea. I asked my friends about how to appropriately making a character that wears a hijab, such as don't give very revealing clothes to the character and don't expose or take off the hijab; but one thing that stops me is that, if I have a character wearing a hijab, does that mean I am including Islam in my story, since Hijab represents a lot about Islam or is it just reference?

I'm asking this as I just want to be respectful and considerate. I'm not sure if I want to include a real religion into the story, but I also would like to ask for some other suggestions and advice for my hijab character. I am still unsure of her, but I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: How much emphasis do you want to put on the character wearing a hijab? Are there situations that are affected by it, or is it just background?

Comment: Well, I just thought inclusions would be a great idea.

Comment: Is your story set in the real world?

Comment: no I don't think so. But I've seen many games that doesn't take place in the real world, yet still have inclusions and diversity from the real world; such as the hijab, Chinese clothing, Cultural music, and other.

Comment: I was not sure if I can do that

Answer (score 5):

When you add a hijab of course you're adding Islam to the mix. But that doesn't necessarily change the plot unless it is focused on religion. Simply adding a character that wears a hijab is just a reference to their religion, this can make the story feel real. And not to mention make the story be representative / inclusive to the religion which is absolutely harmless (and very much needed)
This is just how I tend to go about similar things but of course, there can be many different points of view

Comment: my concerns are that if I do add an actual religion, then there might be some things I need to consider.

Comment: hmm yes, that seems unavoidable. I have a few ocs that are gay, bi, Sikh, pocs, etc but I only develop on things required to the story leaving the rest just as inclusivities.

Comment: One consideration would be if other characters have other religions. Islam is maybe more obvious, but any faith may influence behavior. But as with any religion, there are some Muslims who talk about faith a lot, some who don't talk but maybe act in certain ways, and some who seem to ignore it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a detail to your story, you need to provide adequate level of connections and explanations for this detail.

If this detail is commonplace in your setting, no explanations are needed. You may or may not incorporate this detail in your plot, and either way is fine.

But if this detail is unusual, some explanations are needed, and reader would expect that this detail is important to your characters development or to the plot.